# Steering angle sensor

Tags: mercedes-benz, steering

On my `Mercedes C180`, just got an error about non-functioning steering angle sensor.

I understand it can affect ESP, but how bad in fact is it? Replacement is rather expensive, so I wonder if I can drive without the sensor, and what are the consequences.

Comment: Did you try the "five times, lock to lock" reset procedure?

Comment: @BobCross Do you have a link to that procedure? Or maybe it's in the owner's manual?

Comment: Was the car recently aligned?

Comment: No, it wasn't aligned, looks like the sensor just went down. So I'm  interested in knowing how bad it is to drive without the sensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ESP is Electronic Stability Program. It requires the steering wheel angle sensor to work correctly. With it erroring, the ESP may make bad decisions as to your interest in which direction you want your car to go. Your MB may be smart enough to shut off the ESP when there is a problem in the system. If this is the case, or if you can shut it off manually (usually would have to do this every time you start the vehicle), you shouldn't have any issues. This is with the caveat you will need to be more careful in inclement weather as the ESP will obviously not be working and helping you to control your vehicle. Get it fixed as soon as possible, don't do anything crazy in the mean time, and you should be fine.